# Passenger 3.0 and debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, ruby-debug

I have problems using passenger standalone with a debugger. If I try this:

```
passenger start --debugger
```

I get this error:

```
Your version of ruby-debug is too old. Please upgrade to the latest version.
```

My Ruby is: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02

Ruby debug:
ruby-debug (0.10.3)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.3)

So, has anyone successfully used Passenger 3.0 with a debugger?

Comment: I got stumped by this issue too. I was going to mention that you have to use ruby-debug19, as someone had mentioned to me, but I see you're not using ruby 1.9.2 so that doesn't apply. Assuming you're on rails3 is ruby-debug listed in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't supposed to work, the flag was experimental but we forgot to remove it for 3.0.0, that's why it isn't documented. It'll be removed for 3.0.1.

Comment: So if I want to use a debugger I'll have to stick with WEBrick or Mongrel?

Comment: Yes. ruby-debug assumes a single process *and* a terminal, so it's fundamentally incompatible with Phusion Passenger's multiprocessing model unless special support is added.

Comment: then you guys should remove this message: "***** Debugger requested, but was not available: Start server with --debugger to enable *****" and replace it with something that indicates it is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a debugger in Passenger by using [rack-debug](https://github.com/ddollar/rack-debug)

It works by having a client connect to the Passenger process at the breakpoints you set.  A bit more complicated than using Thing/Mongrel with a debugger.  But pretty simple to setup.